# SQL / PHP: get all results within time X to Y, and detect if there are available times inbetween

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, time

Sorry if the title is a bit vague..

I have a database looking like this:

```
orderid | roomname | date(DATE) | from(TIME) | to(TIME)
```

Example-data:

```
1231 | E12 | 2013-04-05 | 07:00:00 | 10:00:00
1671 | E12 | 2013-04-05 | 13:00:00 | 14:00:00
```

I'm for example searching up a certain date and obviously getting all reservations on that day. 
As you can see on the example-data, the room is available between 10:00:00 and 13:00:00. How can I catch this?

I was thinking about looping through time 07:00:00-16:00:00 (with one query for each) and check if I get any results from sql. If I do get results, I will know that the room is busy, but since there are unknowns here (ex. 08:00:00 and 09:00:00 doesn't exists), I will get false-positives on this.

Any tips here?

Comment: The room is available from 10:00:00 to 13:00:00. Right?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be using a 'calendar table', or if you're only ever interested in one day a 'clock table' would do. The following illustrates (roughly) how you'd use it.

```
SELECT clock.time AS available
FROM clock
LEFT JOIN bookings ON clock.time BETWEEN bookings.from AND bookings.to
                  AND bookings.date = '2013-01-01' 
WHERE bookings.id IS NULL
```

http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables is an example of how to create a calendar in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

With this data:

```
create table rooms
(
  orderid int not null,
  roomname varchar(8) not null,
  date date not null,
  `from` time not null,
  `to` time not null
);

insert into rooms values (1231, 'E12', '2013-04-05', '07:00', '10:00');
insert into rooms values (1671, 'E12', '2013-04-05', '13:00', '14:00');
```

to get the available time interval/slot, you can issue this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(r1.`to`, '%T') AS `From`, DATE_FORMAT(min(r2.`from`), '%T') AS `To`
FROM
  rooms r1 JOIN rooms r2
  ON r1.`to`< r2.`from`
WHERE r1.date = '2013-04-05' AND r1.roomname = 'E12'
GROUP BY r1.`to`
HAVING
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM rooms r3
              WHERE r1.`to` < r3.`to`
              AND min(r2.`from`) > r3.`from`)
```

the above query will return:

```
10:00:00    13:00:00
```

Here's the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c124/25

Note: the above query was kindly adapted from this answer by [@fthiella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833073/fthiella):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14139835/114029

---

With this additional query:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) = 0) AS Available
    FROM rooms
    WHERE roomname = 'E12' AND date = '2013-04-05' AND
    (
        (`from` < MAKETIME(10,00,00) AND `to` > MAKETIME(10,00,00)) OR
        (`from` < MAKETIME(13,00,00) AND `to` > MAKETIME(13,00,00))
    )
```

It'll return `1`, that is, there's no reservation between the given start time (`from`) and end time (`to`) and so the room is available.

Here's the SQL Fiddle to play with the data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c124/1

Comment: This is excellent! It's a bit (or way) over my skill level - How can I add a date into the time/interval-query?

Comment: Just add an `AND r1.date = '2013-04-05'` after `on r1.to < r2.from`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is there any way to add "roomname" into this aswell? Doesn't seem to work with "r1.roomname = ' '" after the date.

Comment: Sure. I added a `WHERE` clause in the query. Updated the answer and the SQL Fiddle.